# How do I configure a KafkaListener to Listen to multiple comma separated topic configured in my properties file?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

Anyone know how do I configure a KafkaListener with multiple topics? Any help would be appreciated.

My Java Code,

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${application.kafka.topics}")
public void listen(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record, Acknowledgment ack) {
    System.out.println(record);
}
```

application.yaml

```
application:
   kafka:
     topics: topic1, topic2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mathew, Thanks for your quick response.

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "#{'${kafka.topics}'.split(',')}")
```

This is something I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If we have to fetch multiple topics from the application.properties file :

```
@KafkaListener(topics = { "${spring.kafka.topic1}", "${spring.kafka.topic2}" })
```

Comment: Yes, this would work. But in my case, the topic names are comma separated. How do I read them?

Comment: @SubhakantPriyadarsan try this: @KafkaListener(topics = "#{'${kafka.topics}'.split(',')}")